# Cache table data for Lambda Processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a use case where in I have a table in the `AWS postgres` database. This is a configuration table ( few rows even less than 100 ) and data stored in this table will be used by `lambda` for some processing. Now, `lambda` has to run multiple times so I don't want it to go and read the table every time from the database. Is there a way to cache the table data (apart from `Redis` option) for `lambda` processing? I was going through the `AWS` extension https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-extensions/tree/main/cache-extension-demo but here in the config file, `dynamoDB` is mentioned. What do I need to mention for `RDS`? Can we even use it for my use case? Does Anyone have a working example?

Is there any other way we can resolve this?

Comment: If your cache data is less than 100 rows you could easily store them in dynamo. Depending on your latency requirements you could also store them in s3 and use a byte offset to read the specific value(s) you need. However, the OPs' question isn't clear.

Comment: @LucasRoberts  we want to store sch data on database side only so that it can be configuration values in that can be changed at any time without any deployment

Comment: I see, I wrote an answer before this was updated on my browser. If the configuration values are going to frequently change then dynamo is probably the preferred option. You can setup a single table that store the values. I included links in my answer to aws lambda docs that describe the setup.

Comment: One thing that isn't mentioned, what is the event/trigger for the lambda to run?

Comment: I removed the idea of coding the <100 rows directly as literals in the lambda code because you mentioned those values would change somewhat often. I also added a discussion of common invocation events and a link to lambda docs on invocations.

Comment: the OPs' link was to a go repo: here is a link to go doc example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/dynamo-example-read-table-item.html

Answer (score 0):

> This is configuration table ( few rows even less than 100 )

Then you could store it in dynamo as the linked repository suggests.
Also the [aws lambda docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) have some documentation for this scenario because it is fairly common.
This makes the most sense if your lambda handler code is unlikely to change but the cached values would need to change more frequently.

> Now lambda has to run multiple times so I don't want it to go and read the table every time from database.

If the requirement is to not read the table for every request then you could use a warm start. Read more about the phases of lambda execution [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html). You could use [provisioned concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html) to reduce latency.

> What do I need to mention for RDS . Can we even use it for my use case?

You can use RDS but would need to setup a connection to the database from lambda and setup your code to use a warm start if faster response times are required.

> Does Anyone has working example .

Yes [here is an example](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/dynamodb-from-python-lambda/q/platform/js/) with working snippets of code in python.
You would want to create the small table in dynamo first-you can do this in the console and confirm the keys/values are as expected. Next you'd create the lambda which reads from dynamo and confirm this reads as expected with a test event. There are [various aws sdk languages here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/lambda_example_lambda_Invoke_section.html) that show how to invoke the lambda from the sdk.

Note: When creating lambda you'd need to define the event that triggers the lambda function. Common examples are: scheduled events from event bridge/cloudwatch, s3 put events, dynamodb table updates, and http requests from api gateway. Other events are possible too, some triggers/invocations are [synchronous while other are async](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/invocation-modes.html)

Comment: Thank you @lucas roberts. But business users doesn't have  access to dynamodb table .they have access to RDS table.so if anything gets updated there I need to write code to update Dynamo from RDS .that's why we were not thinking of using dynamo

Comment: Is there a way we can cache data after reading it once from RDS table and keep it in chache for like 2-3 hrs and then re cache it again

Comment: @pbh there are docs for that too https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html there's some example python code on that page of the docs. You may need to establish network connectivity between the lambda and the RDS instance.